# Replace = with : in serialized data

Tags: javascript, typescript

i'm recieving a serialzed data in the form as

```
error_message=%7B%0D%0A+null+%7D&systemId=53183&cert-id=176061&score=0&q2c=3%5C0&q2t=&answer_data=0000
```

how can i replace the = with : using typescript  and replace should be for all the occurence of = except first that is error_message=value&systemId:value&cert-id=value and so on

i was trying with splice but it seems to be a long process and not that fast as the string grows.

Comment: So you want to replace all the equals except the closest to the ampersands

Comment: ya even that would do good

Comment: Your description doesn't match your example. You want to replace all `=` except the first, or alternating `=` and `:`?

Comment: @LionelRowe all excpet the first

Comment: Since it looks like you are dealing with query string params, I'd suggest exploring [all this related posts dealing with parsing query string params](https://www.google.com/search?q=typescript+parse+query+params+site:stackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by splitting the string by `=` and then treating the first element different from all others:

```js
const input = 'error_message=%7B%0D%0A+null+%7D&systemId=53183&cert-id=176061&score=0&q2c=3%5C0&q2t=&answer_data=0000';

const repl = (inp) => {
  const [firstEl, ...rest] = inp.split(/\=/); // Split by '='
  return `${firstEl}=${rest.join(':')}`; // <first el> + '=' + <all other elements joined by ':'>
}
console.log(repl(input));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the first '=' with the method [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf), then [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) the string into the two different parts (one before the first '=' and one after) and [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) the following equal signs

```js
const string = "error_message=%7B%0D%0A+null+%7D&systemId=53183&cert-id=176061&score=0&q2c=3%5C0&q2t=&answer_data=0000"

const firstSignIndex = string.indexOf('=')
const result = string.slice(0, firstSignIndex+1) + string.slice(firstSignIndex+1).replace(/=/g, ':')

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like these are URL search query parameters, so you can get them in a more manageable format using the `URLSearchParams` constructor, then manipulate them however you want:

```js
const queryString = 'error_message=%7B%0D%0A+null+%7D&systemId=53183&cert-id=176061&score=0&q2c=3%5C0&q2t=&answer_data=0000'

const [ first, ...rest ] = [...new URLSearchParams(queryString)]
    .map(([k, v]) => [k, v].map(encodeURIComponent))
    // assuming you still want URI encoding, else remove mapping

const result = [
    first.join(':'),
    ...rest.map(x => x.join('=')),
].join('&')

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out, this will help you to replace the `=` with `:` except the first occurrence of `=` in your serialized string.

```js
let a = 'error_message=%7B%0D%0A+null+%7D&systemId=53183&cert-id=176061&score=0&q2c=3%5C0&q2t=&answer_data=0000',

firstOcc = a.indexOf("error_message=") + 'error_message='.length,

starterStr = a.substring(0, firstOcc),

replacedStr = a.substring(firstOcc, a.length).replace(/=/g, ':');

console.log(starterStr + replacedStr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You can make changes based on your needs `firstOcc = a.indexOf("error_message=") + 'error_message='.length,`